# Wordpress automatically adding comments to inserted PHP code how to disable?

Tags: php

When I insert my PHP code using a button in the Wordpress page/post editor to add custom scripted php items such as buttons, authors, infopanes and such my own custom scripted item, which includes a bunch of connecting to a database and filling in information automatically from a database in a table it inserts <--php ?--> instead of me mentioning tags, I've installed exec-php which allows me to use the php tags.

If I copy all code myself in the wordpress text editor the tags won't be changed into comments and everything works perfectly in the page, the table loads and inserts information from the table I extract out of the database.

However if I use the button (Shortcodes it is called) and insert all extract same code in the Wordpress page post box it adds comments to my php, i was wondering if there is a way to turn this off so it doesn't break my code.

I tried using a different plugin which used [insert_php] and [/insert_php] it worked in making the tags dissappear but it didn't actually do anything itself, it didn't connect to the database or fill in the tables.

Comment: do you mean exec-php, the plugin that hasn't been updated in over 2 years since before WP version 3? please don't execute php in post content, it's a huge security risk. put your php in a custom shortcode instead.

Comment: I'm not using shortcode exec php plugin, this is a button which looks like this: [LINK](http://i.cubeupload.com/8bxaOJ.png) . And if I press an option it will drop in whatever the option should do, in my case you can select an ID number, anything and then it drops a html+php code to make a page have a table on it that extracted data from a database.

Comment: Got it, using a shortcode now. thx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Done it using Shortcodes (Thanks Milo).